# Where can I find challenging topology questions

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

I was hoping someone might be able to refer me to a collection of hard(er) general topology questions at undergraduate level. Many thanks!

Comment: consider exercises in *Munkres'* textbook

Comment: You might want to give examples of what you DON'T consider as hard problems (e.g. problems in a book, which you cite for us), because when I clicked on this question, Munkres' text (which two people have mentioned, and no other book or source has yet been mentioned) is definitely NOT what I would have expected to have been what you were looking for, as that's one of the most widely used undergraduate/graduate topology texts (i.e. I don't see this book as being especially distinguished in any way except in being very readable and widely used).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro I have been using course materials and exams rather than books for topology, so I can't cite a book. However the level of problems I was hoping for was similar to the level of Putnam problems... so problems where alot of independent thought is needed and that are less standard

Comment: Kelley's [**General Topology**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0387901256) has a lot of substantial problems, many of which are mini-projects. Wilansky's [**Topology for Analysis**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0486469034)  has a large number of problems and they are grouped by numbers less than 100 (should be solvable by readers with an appropriate understanding of the material), in the 100's ("special and somewhat challenging"), in the 200's ("may be extremely difficult"), where the quoted phrases are from p. vii, the 2nd paragraph of the Preface. There are a lot of problems of all 3 types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that you're asking for harder problems, I disagree with the suggestion of Munkres. Sorry for being blunt, but that book is really targeted at people with a low level of mathematical maturity.

I won't suggest reference books on topology like Dugundji, Engelking or Bourbaki either, because the problems will be divided among the chapters and often connected with specialized advanced material in each chapter.

Instead, I'd suggest either the topology chapters in books on analysis or introductory books on topology written at a higher level than Munkres. Here are some examples.

- *General Topology* by Willard. (In this case, the problem with specialized material occurs to some extent.)
- *Topology* by Choquet.
- The topology chapters of *Real and Functional Analysis* by Lang. (Don't forget to look at the parts on normed vector spaces in this book or any other. Even basic material on Euclidean space is to be found there.)
- Volume 2 of *Mathematical Analysis* by Zorich (Chapter 9 and Sections 10.1, 10.2).
- *Treatise on Analysis* by Dieudonné. Chapters III-VII (in Volume 1, on metric spaces, the real line, normed vector spaces, Hilbert spaces, and spaces of functions) and Chapter XII (in Volume 2, on general topology).

Answer (score 0):

*Topology* by Munkres (inventive name as with most math books) has many good exercises, some of which are very challenging. The undergraduate topology course I took used this book and I feel that it gave me a solid background in topology, and I remember it well over a decade later despite not ending up specializing in it.

Comment: Cheers! Will give it a look!